# MySQL - group by resulting in duplicate rows

Tags: mysql, group-by, subquery

Given the following data:

```
CREATE TABLE Bugs
    (`ID` int, `BugDate` DATE, `resolved` int)
;

INSERT INTO Bugs
    (`ID`, `BugDate`, `Resolved`)
VALUES
    (1, '2014-01-01', 1),
    (2, '2014-01-01', 0),
    (3, '2014-01-10', 1),
    (4, '2014-01-10', 1),
    (5, '2014-01-31', 0),
    (6, '2014-01-31', 0)
;
```

I need output like the following:

```
weeks old  Resolved  Unresolved  total  Rate
---------  --------  ----------  -----  ----
    1        1            1        2     50%
    2        2            0        2    100%
    3        0            2        0    100%
```

I am looking at a list of issues and I want to see the total number each week and the number resolved each week. I've accepted that I'll probably need to calculate the total and rate columns in the front-end rather that having MySQL do it.

I have tried the following, but it's not quite getting there:

```
SELECT
  WEEKOFYEAR(NOW())-WEEKOFYEAR(BugDate) as WeeksOld,
  COUNT(Resolved) as NumberResolved,
  ( /* get the total number of issues for this time period */
    SELECT COUNT(Resolved)
    FROM Bugs
    WHERE WEEKOFYEAR(NOW())-WEEKOFYEAR(BugDate) = WeeksOld
  ) - COUNT(Resolved) as Unresolved
FROM Bugs
GROUP BY WEEKOFYEAR(NOW())-WEEKOFYEAR(BugDate), Resolved
ORDER BY WeeksOld DESC;
```

I'm so close, but the problem is, I'm getting double columns for weeks where there are both resolved and unresolved issues.

What am I missing?  Is there a better way to do this?

Here is a fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/eeb34/12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just want conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT WEEKOFYEAR(NOW())-WEEKOFYEAR(BugDate) as WeeksOld,
       SUM(Resolved) as NumberResolved,
       SUM(1 - Resolved) as Unresolved,
       concat(format(AVG(Resolved)*100, 1), '%') as Rate
FROM Bugs
GROUP BY WEEKOFYEAR(NOW())-WEEKOFYEAR(BugDate)
ORDER BY WeeksOld DESC;
```

Note that this removes `Resolved` from the `group by`.  It changes the calculation of `resolved` to use `sum()` rather than `count()`.  It adds the `Rate` column.  And it changes the calculation of `Unresolved`.  You could write the latter as:

```
count(*) - sum(Resolved)
```

Comment: That is mysql kung fu genius. Thank you. No "Total" Column, but I can calculate that.

Answer (score 1):

Don't group by Resolved -
the last two lines should be

```
GROUP BY WEEKOFYEAR(NOW())-WEEKOFYEAR(BugDate)
ORDER BY WeeksOld DESC;
```

Comment: Nice catch. But the other answer gave me a more obvious way or reaching my goal. Thank you.